# Is it good to NULL a Collection object?

Tags: java, collections

At some point in my code I want to nullify a Collection object. Is it possible for memory leak by doing so?

```
  Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>("Test");
  ...
  ...
  set = null;
  if(set == null){
     ... 
  }
```

Comment: Just so you know - that's not valid syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You don't nullify an *object* - you change a *variable*'s value to `null`. It's really, really important that you understand the difference between objects, variables and references.

That's rarely useful, but it would be extremely odd to lead to a variable leak in itself. I can't immediately think how that could happen - unless you had some nullity check which changed your behaviour regarding *other* data, of course. It *may* make the collection that the previous variable value referred to eligible for garbage collection, or it may not - it depends on whether anything else still has a reference to it.

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to nullify the object referred to by the variable that's being null?

Comment: @martin: I'm afraid I don't even know how to parse your question. But "nullity the object" simply isn't a meaningful term. Changing the value of the variable does *nothing* to the object that the variable's value used to refer to.

Answer (score 2):

No.  It is not possible to create a memory leak by nulling your collection object.

Incidentally, part of the code above is pointless: If you set `set` to null, testing it for null right afterwards is a null-op.

Comment: This doesn't reflect the full picture of the code. I just want to make sure it's ok to set it to null, so later on set will be reassigned with another set object.

Comment: @TheThom: it might not.  Some complilers/jvms will optimize it away. But even if they don't, it's still pointless code.  It's essentially testing that the assignment worked.